# verfying a set identity involving disjoint sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(E_n)$ is a sequence of sets. We know from these sets we can form disjoint sets by the following trick:

$$ F_k = E_k \cap \bigg( \bigcup_{j=1}^{k-1} E_j \bigg)^c $$

I am trying to show that $\bigcup_{k\geq1} F_k = \bigcup_{k \geq 1} E_k $.

What I have tried:

if $x \in \bigcup F_k $ then $x \in F_l$ for some $l$. which means $x \in E_l $ for some $l$ which means $x \in \bigcup E_k$ by definition

Conversely, if $x \in \bigcup E_k$, then $x \in E_l$ for some $l$. Suppose $x \notin \bigcup F_k $ so $x \in \bigcap E_k^c $ which means $x \in E_k^c $ for all $k$ which means $x \notin E_k$ for all $k$. In particular $x \notin E_l$ which contradicts original assumption that $x \in E_l$. We conclude that $x \in \bigcup F_k $

Is this a correct approach?

I was thinking of using an algebra of sets approach as follows

$$ \bigcup F_k = \bigcup \bigg( E_k \cap \bigg( \bigcup_j^{k-1} E_k \bigg)^c  \bigg) = \bigcup \bigg( E_1^c \cap ... \cap E_{k-1}^c \cap E_k \bigg) $$

But here I get stuck.

Comment: It is true. It is on my book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bigcup_k F_k \subseteq \bigcup_k E_k$ is clear.

Conversely, if $x \in \bigcup_k E_k$, then the following is well defined
$$m= \min \{ k  : x \in E_k\}$$
since $\{ k  : x \in E_k\}$ is not empty. Then you have $x \in E_m$ and $x \notin E_1 \cup \dots E_{m-1}$. So
$$x \in F_m \subseteq \bigcup_k F_k$$

Comment: Thanks for your time. So, you are saying that I have a mistake on the converse direction, where is it ?

Comment: @Anonaki "Suppose $x \notin \bigcup F_k $ so $x \in \bigcap E_k^c $" is not justified.

Comment: if $x \notin \bigcup F_k $ then $x \in ( \bigcup F_k )^c $ and so $x \in \bigcap F_k^c $ by Demorgans, no ?

Comment: @Anonaki OK, but then how do you conclude that $x \in \bigcap E_k^c$? There is no evidence that $\bigcap F_k^c \subseteq \bigcap E_k^c $.

Comment: With regards to your argument, Why is it that $x \in E_m$ ? We know that $x \in \bigcup E_k $ which means $x$ is in some of the $E_k's$. How are we certain that $x$ must lie in $E_m $ ?

Comment: It is the definition of $m$. $m$ is the minimum index such that $x \in E_m$.

Comment: I understand now. So, the hypothesis that $x \in \bigcup E_k $ is being used to show that the number $m$ is well defined. Correct?

Comment: @Anonaki Exactly.